# str error when pulling XML url to Dataframe. Any idea how I can fix this?

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe

I'm trying to pull data from an xml into a dataframe, and I keep running into issues. The url is this: https://www.dmo.gov.uk/data/XmlDataReport?reportCode=D1A

My attempt to pull the data is here:

```
import pandas as pd
import bs4
import requests
response = requests.get('https://www.dmo.gov.uk/data/XmlDataReport?reportCode=D1A')
in_issue = bs.find_all("View_GILTS_IN_ISSUE")

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['TIME_PERIOD','MATURITY_BRACKET', 'INSTRUMENT_NAME', 'REDEMPTION_DATE', 'FIRST_ISSUE_DATE', 'CLOSE_OF_BUSINESS_DATE'])


for node in in_issue:
    df = df.append({'INSTRUMENT_TYPE': node.get("INSTRUMENT_TYPE"), 'ISIN_CODE': node.get("ISIN_CODE"),'INSTRUMENT_NAME': node.get("INSTRUMENT_NAME")}, ignore_index=True)
    
df.head()
```

The error I get is:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'descendants'
```

Does anyone how I can get past this issue and complete the project? Grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure what your expected output is, but you're better off using panda's `read_xml` method, in this case, and do something like:

```
#load the table
tab = pd.read_xml(response.text)

#select unnecessary columns to drop and drop them
cols = [1,4,7,8,9,10,11]
new_tab=tab.drop(tab.columns[cols],axis=1)

#finally, rearrange the columns
new_tab = new_tab[['MATURITY_BRACKET', 'INSTRUMENT_NAME', 'REDEMPTION_DATE', 'FIRST_ISSUE_DATE', 
 'CLOSE_OF_BUSINESS_DATE']]
new_tab
```

Output:

```
   MATURITY_BRACKET     INSTRUMENT_NAME     REDEMPTION_DATE     FIRST_ISSUE_DATE    CLOSE_OF_BUSINESS_DATE
0   Ultra-Short     0½% Treasury Gilt 2022  2022-07-22T00:00:00     2016-08-03T00:00:00     2022-03-11T00:00:00
1   Ultra-Short     1¾% Treasury Gilt 2022  2022-09-07T00:00:00     2012-06-22T00:00:00     2022-03-11T00:00:00
2   Ultra-Short     0 1/8% Treasury Gilt 2023   2023-01-31T00:00:00     2020-04-08T00:00:00     2022-03-11T00:00:00
```

etc. Obviously, you may need to modify this to get your actual expected output.

Comment: And `read_xml` can directly read the URL XML without `requests`!